# make conda user a different condarc config file

Tags: conda

For some reason, I have conda created multiple .condarc and package locations:

- P:\ .condarc
- C:\Users\lqk4061.condarc

I am suspecting that this has to do with my MINGW64 changing home directory locations.

I have the current output:
[image]

How do I change the user config file to point to `C:\Users\lqk4061\.condarc` instead?

Comment: Looks like this isn't supported right now https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6902